# Bison/Flex, reduce/reduce, identifier in different production

Tags: programming-languages, bison, flex-lexer

I am doing a parser in bison/flex.

This is part of my code:

[image]

I want to implement the assignment production, so the identifier can be both boolean_expr or expr, its type will be checked by a symbol table.
So it allows something like:

```
int a = 1;
boolean b = true;
if(b) ...
```

However, it is reduce/reduce if I include identifier in both term and boolean_expr, any solution to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, what you are trying to do is to inject semantic rules (type information) into your syntax. That's possible, but it is not easy. More importantly, it's rarely a good idea. It's almost always best if syntax and semantics are well delineated.

All the same, as presented your grammar is unambiguous and `LALR(1)`. However, the latter feature is fragile, and you will have difficulty maintaining it as you complete the grammar.

For example, you don't include your assignment syntax in your question, but it would

```
assignment: identifier '=' expr
          | identifier '=' boolean_expr
          ;
```

Unlike the rest of the part of the grammar shown, that production is ambiguous, because:

```
x = y
```

without knowing anything about `y`, `y` could be reduced to either `term` or `boolean_expr`.

A possibly more interesting example is the addition of parentheses to the grammar. The obvious way of doing that would be to add two productions:

```
term: '(' expr ')'

boolean_expr: '(' boolean_expr ')'
```

The resulting grammar is not ambiguous, but it is no longer `LALR(1)`. Consider the two following declarations:

```
boolean x = (y) < 7
boolean x = (y)
```

In the first one, `y` must be an `int` so that `(y)` can be reduced to a `term`; in the second one `y` must be `boolean` so that `(y)` can be reduced to a `boolean_expr`. There is no ambiguity; once the `<` is seen (or not), it is entirely clear which reduction to choose. But `<` is not the lookahead token, and in fact it could be arbitrarily distant from `y`:

```
boolean x = ((((((((((((((((((((((y...
```

So the resulting unambiguous grammar is not `LALR(k)` for any `k`.

---

One way you could solve the problem would be to inject the type information at the lexical level, by giving the scanner access to the symbol table. Then the scanner could look a scanned identifier token in the symbol table and use the information in the symbol table to decide between one of three token types (or more, if you have more datatypes): `undefined_variable`, `integer_variable`, and `boolean_variable`. Then you would have, for example:

```
declaration: "int" undefined_variable '=' expr
           | "boolean" undefined_variable '=' boolean_expr
           ;

term: integer_variable
    | ...
    ;

boolean_expr: boolean_variable
            | ...
            ;
```

That will work but it should be obvious that this is not scalable: every time you add a type, you'll have to extend both the grammar and the lexical description, because the now the semantics is not only mixed up with the syntax, it has even gotten intermingled with the lexical analysis. Once you let semantics out of its box, it tends to contaminate everything.

There are languages for which this really is the most convenient solution: C parsing, for example, is much easier if typedef names and identifier names are distinguished so that you can tell whether `(t)*x` is a cast or a multiplication. (But it doesn't work so easily for C++, which has much more complicated name lookup rules, and also much more need for semantic analysis in order to find the correct parse.)

But, honestly, I'd suggest that you do *not* use C -- and much less C++ -- as a model of how to design a language. Languages which are hard for compilers to parse are also hard for human beings to parse. The ["most vexing parse"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) continues to be a regular source of pain for C++ newcomers, and even sometimes trips up relatively experienced programmers:

```
class X {
  public:
    X(int n = 0) : data_is_available_(n) {}
    operator bool() const { return data_is_available_; }
    // ...
  private:
    bool data_is_available_;
    // ...
};

X my_x_object();
// ...
if (!x) {
  // This code is unreachable. Can you see why?
}
```

In short, you're best off with a language which can be parsed into an AST without any semantic information at all. Once the parser has produced the AST, you can do semantic analyses in separate passes, one of which will check type constraints. That's far and away the cleanest solution. Without explicit typing, the grammar is slightly simplified, because an `expr` now can be any `expr`:

```
 expr:        conjunction | expr "or" conjunction ;
 conjunction: comparison  | conjunction "and" comparison ;
 comparison:  product     | product '<' product ;
 product:     factor      | product '*' factor ;
 factor:      term        | factor '+' term ;
 term:        identifier
     |        constant
     |        '(' expr ')'
     ;
```

Each action in the above would simply create a new AST node and set `$$` to the new node. At the end of the parse, the AST is walked to verify that all `expr`s have the correct type.

If that seems like overkill for your project, you can do the semantic checks in the reduction actions, effectively intermingling the AST walk with the parse. That might seem convenient for immediate evaluation, but it also requires including explicit type information in the parser's semantic type, which adds unnecessary overhead (and, as mentioned, the inelegance of letting semantics interfere with the parser.) In that case, every action would look something like this:

```
expr : expr '+' expr { CheckArithmeticCompatibility($1, $3);
                       $$ = NewArithmeticNode('+', $1, $3);
                     }
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually I am quite new to bison, started to learn it 2 weeks ago. I have a symbol table to check the type but I cannot see how it helps to solve this problem. Before doing the semantic checks in reduction, it has to reduce identifier to expr, right? Similarly the identifier has be to reduced to a boolean_expr if its type is boolean.      I am just making a simple parser with only 3 types: integer, boolean and point, so I would think that it could be easy if I add a prefix to each type of variable, like an integer variable starts with "i_"?

Comment: @user2716189: There's no need to prefix your variables, since your lexer can just look the type of a variable up in the symbol table (assuming it has access to the symbol table). Undeclared variables can only be used as the target of a declaration, and declared variables cannot be redeclared (that's an assumption but it seems reasonable), so the scanner can return one of three token types for the three cases. I tried to make that more explicit in the answer.